# Query string parameters are not working to slice the data after publishing report

Tags: url, powerbi, url-parameters

I have created a report where I created one calculated column which holds the value of dynamic URL. It has ID as parameter and I want to slice the data based upon that after publishing. When I am publishing this report to powerbi.com and I am using this URL to filter out the data, it shows me all the data. The filters through URL is not working.

I just went through a blog and when publishing through query string parameter it says that it has a limitation that it doesn't work when it will be published to web. What does it mean?

Below is the calculated column:

```
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/ce347380-637d-4700-838f-f7b00294256c/reports/374c3b7b-18f0-46f6-b5ec-2c97cbb01611/ReportSection?filter=Append1/Append1[SIMPrjReqID] eq '"&Append1[SIMPrjReqID]&"'
```

where `Append1` is table and `SIMPrjReqID` is a column on which I want to filter out the data dynamically.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

> it has a limitation that it doesn't work when it will be published to web. What does it mean?

This means that passing URL query string parameters to filter data works only when applied on the report's URL, as you see it in the browser's address bar when you open it in powerbi.com, and not on the URL that you get when you use `Publish to web` option to make it public:

[image]

[image]

This filter does not work, because you didn't specified the field name correctly:

```
?filter=Append1/Append1[SIMPrjReqID] eq '"&Append1[SIMPrjReqID]&"'
```

As noted in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters#query-string-parameter-syntax-for-filtering), the filter is passed in this format `URL?filter=Table/Field eq 'value'`, where `Field` is the name of the field. So your query string parameter should look like this:

```
?filter=Append1/SIMPrjReqID eq '"&Append1[SIMPrjReqID]&"'
```

Comment: Really Thanks Andrey! I am trying to implement as per the above idea but when I am trying to open this URL Ia m facing a new error which is prompting like::  "Sorry We couldn't find the report;It may have been deleted or you may not have access to view it" ...However my login is admin for the data source and i have already added it in the sharing report option. We are taking this data from sharepoint portal and all the role are from there. Due to this error I am not able to check whether these filters are working or not.   Can you please suggest!Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you get "could not find the report" error, then your URL (the part before `?`) is incorrect. Remove the query string parameters (the question mark and everything after it) and you should see the report. If you don't, then navigate from the menu to this report and get the correct URL from the address bar.

Comment: Adding invalid filters in the URL will not lead to such error. You will see the report unfiltered and in the filters pane you will see an error about the added filter.

Comment: Yes you were right;I was using a different url.Its working fine.You are a star.Thanks a lot!!!!!!